# Having trouble re-indexing my array after looping from the end of the array while adding characters in place

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, for-loop, splice

I am trying to solve this particular algorithm question:

You are given a license key represented as a string S which consists only alphanumeric character and dashes. The string is separated into N+1 groups by N dashes.

Given a number K, we would want to reformat the strings such that each group contains exactly K characters, except for the first group which could be shorter than K, but still must contain at least one character. Furthermore, there must be a dash inserted between two groups and all lowercase letters should be converted to uppercase.

Given a non-empty string S and a number K, format the string according to the rules described above.

Example 1:
Input: S = "5F3Z-2e-9-w", K = 4

Output: "5F3Z-2E9W"

Explanation: The string S has been split into two parts, each part has 4 characters.
Note that the two extra dashes are not needed and can be removed.
Example 2:
Input: S = "2-5g-3-J", K = 2

Output: "2-5G-3J"

Explanation: The string S has been split into three parts, each part has 2 characters except the first part as it could be shorter as mentioned above.
Note:
The length of string S will not exceed 12,000, and K is a positive integer.
String S consists only of alphanumerical characters (a-z and/or A-Z and/or 0-9) and dashes(-).
String S is non-empty.

I have written the following code:

```
const licenseKeyFormatting = (S, K) => {
    //convert to array, remove special characters, and capitalize
    let s = [...S.replace(/\W/g, '').toUpperCase()]
    let pos = 1
    //from end of array add '-' for every K
    for (let i = s.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (pos === K) {
            s.splice(i, 0, '-')
            pos = 1
            i-- //re-index bc adding to the array
        }
        pos++
    }
    return s
}


console.log(licenseKeyFormatting("5F3Z-2e-9-w", 4)) //5F3Z-2E9W
console.log(licenseKeyFormatting("2-5g-3-J", 2)) //2-5G-3J
console.log(licenseKeyFormatting("a-a-a-a-", 1)) // this test case fails should be A-A-A-A, I am getting AAA-A
```

I am pretty sure the flaw in my logic is due to the re-index, but I can't figure out how to address it.

Comment: added new answer (more simple and not ninja code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not alter the index. Using `splice` to insert an element pushes the other elements back, however since you iterate from back to front that doesn't matter. You've already handled the shifted elements.

Another issue is setting `pos = 1` in the loop. This is directly followed by `pos++`. So when `pos` reaches `K` the value of `pos` will be reset to `2` at the end of the loop. Either set `pos = 0` (in the loop) so it ends on `1` or move `pos++` into the `else` section.

```js
const licenseKeyFormatting = (S, K) => {
    //convert to array, remove special characters, and capitalize
    let s = [...S.replace(/\W/g, '').toUpperCase()]
    let pos = 1
    //from end of array add '-' for every K
    for (let i = s.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (pos === K) {
            s.splice(i, 0, '-')
            pos = 0
        }
        pos++
    }
    return s.join("") // <- added join for cleaner console output
}


console.log(licenseKeyFormatting("5F3Z-2e-9-w", 4)) //5F3Z-2E9W
console.log(licenseKeyFormatting("2-5g-3-J", 2)) //2-5G-3J
console.log(licenseKeyFormatting("a-a-a-a-", 1)) // this test case fails should be A-A-A-A, I am getting AAA-A
```

Answer (score 1):

my way....

```js
function licenseKeyFormatting( S, K )
  {
  let arr = [...S.replace(/\W/g, '').toUpperCase()]
    , p   = 0
    ;
  for (let i=arr.length;i--;)
    {
    p = ++p % K                     // p = (p+1) % K
    if (!p&&i) arr.splice(i,0,'-')  // if p===0 and i>0
    }
  return arr.join('')
  }


console.log(licenseKeyFormatting("5F3Z-2e-9-w", 4)) // 5F3Z-2E9W
console.log(licenseKeyFormatting("2-5g-3-J", 2))   //  2-5G-3J
console.log(licenseKeyFormatting("a-a-a-a-", 1))  //   A-A-A-A
```

> OR: (more simple)

```js
function licenseKeyFormatting( S, K )
  {
  let arr = [...S.replace(/\W/g, '').toUpperCase()];
  for (let p=arr.length-K;p>0;p-=K) arr.splice(p,0,'-');
  return arr.join('');
  }


console.log( licenseKeyFormatting("5F3Z-2e-9-w", 4)) // 5F3Z-2E9W
console.log( licenseKeyFormatting("2-5g-3-J", 2))   //  2-5G-3J
console.log( licenseKeyFormatting("a-a-a-a-", 1))  //   A-A-A-A
```